# How to get artificactId of dependencies in Maven?

Tags: maven

I have multi-module project. Dependencies are as follows:

```
<dependencies>              
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.gwr</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwr-commons</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.gwr</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwr-places-module</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.gwr</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwr-devices-module</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.gwr</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwr-events-module</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.gwr</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwr-controls-module</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.gwr</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwr-logs-module</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

And, under `src/main/resources` of each module/dependency I have one ZIP file named as `<module>-persistence.zip` (e.g. `C:\gwr-logs-module\src\main\resources\logs-persistence.zip`). I want to copy this ZIP file of each module under some other directory let us say `C:\users\user\project`. I have defined `maven-resources-plugin` as below:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-presubscriptionfiles</id>
            <phase>validate</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-resources</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>${user.home}/${dasmo.storage}/</outputDirectory>
                <overwrite>true</overwrite>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>${basedir}/../gwr-logs-module/src/main/resources</directory>
                        <includes>
                            <include>*.zip</include>
                        </includes>
                    </resource>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>${basedir}/../gwr-devices-module/src/main/resources</directory>
                        <includes>
                            <include>*.zip</include>
                        </includes>
                    </resource>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>${basedir}/../gwr-controls-module/src/main/resources</directory>
                        <includes>
                            <include>*.zip</include>
                        </includes>
                    </resource>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>${basedir}/../gwr-events-module/src/main/resources</directory>
                        <includes>
                            <include>*.zip</include>
                        </includes>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

As you see, under resource section I have to hard code each module name. How can I avoid this? Can't we use `artifactId` of each dependency? If yes, how to use it? Or is there any other way to do this job?

Thank you so much.
regards,
Yeshwant

Comment: I don't understand your question. http://books.sonatype.com/mvnex-book/reference/multimodule.html

Comment: Dovy, can you please tell me which part you did not understood in my question: Please see the code I have written. I have to write down name of all modules one after another which I want to avoid while doing resource copy:

Comment: My question is how can I get value of artifactId from "<artifactId>gwr-logs-module</artifactId>" in my resource plugin. <artifactId>gwr-logs-module</artifactId> is taken from dependencies defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reduce the `<plugin>` section in your multi-module POM to the following:

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>copy-presubscriptionfiles</id>
      <!-- Note: this phase is more appropriate than 'validate' -->
      <phase>process-resources</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>copy-resources</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <outputDirectory>${user.home}/${dasmo.storage}</outputDirectory>
        <overwrite>true</overwrite>
        <resources>
          <resource>
            <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</directory> 
            <!-- or likewise
            <directory>${project.projectDirectory}/src/main/resources</directory>
            -->
            <includes>
              <include>*.zip</include>
            </includes>
          </resource>
        </resources>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

If you declare your multi-module project as `<parent>` in any of your sub-module POMs this will be inherited by them (see [Introduction to the POM, Project Inheritance](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html#Project_Inheritance)) and such performed at each sub-module build.

Note: `basedir` is deprecated in favor of [`project.basedir.`](http://maven.apache.org/components/ref/3-LATEST/maven-model-builder#Model_Interpolation)

See [Maven: The Complete Reference, Multi-module vs. Inheritance](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/pom-relationships-sect-pom-best-practice.html#pom-relationships-sect-multi-vs-inherit) for further reading.